# Can a sponsored spouse buy a house in Canada while her permanent resident application is still being processed?

Tags: canada, real-estate, housing, permanent-resident

I will get married with my Canadian partner, and plan to buy a house for us in Canada. However, I am currently not a permanent resident of Canada yet. I will apply for being a permanent resident of Canada right after getting married under the category of "sponsored spouse". However, this type of application is known to take around one year to be processed and finalized. So, my question is that: "**Can I** (the person who is sponsored by my Canadian partner) **buy a house alone under my name while waiting for the final result of permanet resident application with the same procedure as any other permanent residents and Canadians**?"

Or will I be charged by tax department as a foreigner if I buy the house under my name alone?

Or does the house have to be bought and signed by both me and my Canadian partner?

Comment: This obviously relates to Vancouver, where a foreign buyers tax was recently introduced in an effort to cool the market.  The rule states : "Anyone who isn’t a permanent resident of Canada is a foreign national, and thus subject to the new rule."  Therefore, unless you have resident status you are subject to the tax.  I assume this covers the period while your application is being processed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response to my question. But, do you have any idea if I buy the house together with my Canadian husband? Will I be taxed or partially taxed when the house is bought and signed by both of us?

Comment: If you are a Canadian resident, then the tax will not apply.  If you wait until your spouse has resident status, then there should be no problem in changing the title on the deeds, other than the legal expenses.  Since you are buying a property, you will need to use a lawyer.  They will be able to steer you into the most tax efficient way of completing your purchase.  Good luck.